# Invoking Windows EC2 terminal remotely

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I need to connect to my Windows EC2 terminal to invoke a local script on it from a different machine CMD.

I tried to search and I 'v found the following: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Connect-using-EC2-Instance-Connect.html.  This solves the problem for Linux, not windows. Any suggestion or lead for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows machines, you can remotely SSH onto your EC2 instance using a bash shell, which supports SSH.

If you have git bash installed, it can do the trick for you.

You will need the pem file which you can generate before launching your EC2 instance, at the very last step. Else, you can also use your own key - see docs from AWS [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html#ec2-instance-connect-connecting-aws-cli).

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the option of session manager.

Please refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html

To give you a brief, Session Manager is a fully managed AWS Systems Manager capability that lets you manage your Amazon EC2 instances, on-premises instances, and virtual machines (VMs) through an interactive one-click browser-based shell or through the AWS CLI.